# Bash backspace character correct use

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I did a pretty simple thing.

```
echo -e "123\b4" >> simple
cat simple
124
```

But when I open this file in Sublime text I get some characters called "BS" which probabvly stands for backspace, and when i open it with gedit I get a space instead and 4 after the space. which is the correct version of the file?

and when I open the file on the commandline with vim I get a

```
^H
```

character instead.

Can someone please offer guidance?

Comment: See `man ascii` decimal value `8`. Also the output from `printf %q\\n ^H` and `printf %s ^H | xxd`.

Comment: Yes that cleared it up :)

Comment: `123\b4` and `124` are two different strings, although certain programs may *display* them identically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct version of the file is the one saved on the filesystem. Sublime text and gedit are reading the file and representing in different ways.

Comment: Again: vim is representing the file in another way. 

All those editor are using a different kind of "extended" characters, but they all are representing the same value: the backspace.

Comment: Right, I understand. Is there anyway I can reflect the filesystem representation in any one of these editors?

Comment: Basically because I have to edit these files and the presence of "BS"s floating around is disconcerting

Comment: @SrinivasSuresh running `xxd simple` will show you exactly what bytes are saved in there. Unless you asked about the editor showing what is on the disk... in that case they already do that. You see the backspace as `^H` in vim - this is the representation of what's on the disk.

Comment: Since all the editor are "correctly" representing this character I think you can pick the one that better fits you needs. I prefer vim, it's more compact (as you noticed, there's only a ^H character per each backspace).
Anyway if you must filter out all those characters, you can use tr with something like: `cat filename|tr -d '\b'`

Comment: Thanks StefanoF and viraptor. Sorry for piggybacking on the initial question :)

Answer (score 1):

`\b` simply takes cursor to left by single character. Its upto each editors interpretation to this symbol!